# ionic 4 ion-button not works

Tags: ionic-framework, angular7

I try to implement a button in ionic 4 with ion-button but there is no style out, where can the problem lay, help.

[image]

Comment: Can you show a reproduction with your HTML code ?

Comment: Can you give your `package.json` or a github minimal reproduction repository ?

Answer (score 6):

Please use below code

```
<ion-button color="secondary"></ion-button>
```

here is document for ionic v4 button.
https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/button

Comment: I tried it and put out the same thing in the picture.

Comment: I think the problem is with Ionic library or something, I do not know it. Do you have an idea.

Comment: please attach your source link. It seems you missed some libraries.

Comment: Here's the link to the non-beta Ionic 4 ion-button documentation. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button

Answer (score 1):

I think you started project without angular.
if you want to use button in your ionic project better you give ion-button inside a button.

```
 <button ion-button>Start</button>
```

I am sure it will work properly.

Comment: This is the way it works in ionic 3, not in ionic 4.

Comment: But i am using.In all version.

Answer (score 0):

use *--background* property in the CSS class ion-button if you want a custom background.

```
<ion-button color="primary">Primary</ion-button>
```

> in the above example the button background must be your primary color

use [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button) for more information.